# Retrieving XML attributes to a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, lxml

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<foo bar1="1" bar2="2" bar3="23" bar4="4">
    <baz abc1="xxx" abc2="yyy">
        <item1 a="0" b="123"/>
        <item2 a="0" b="124"/>
        <item3>blue</item3>
        <item4>green</item4>
        <item5>yellow</item5>
        <item6>red</item6>
        <item7>white</item7>
```

I'm able to retrieve items contained in `item1`, `item2`, etc. Now I want to retrieve the attributes contained in `foo` or `baz`, like `bar1` or `abc1`.

Everything will be sent to a pandas DataFrame. Code below. Notice that `col1` and `col2` are returning `None`.

```
from lxml import objectify
import pandas as pd

xml = objectify.parse('file.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

data = []

for i in range(len(root.getchildren())):
    data.append([child.text for child in root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()])

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item5', 'item6', 'item7']

df.head()

   item1  item2 item3     item4    item5   item6   item7
0  None    None   blue    green   yellow    red    white
1  None    None   blue    green   yellow    red    white
2  None    None   blue    green   yellow    red    white
3  None    None   blue    green   yellow    red    white
4  None    None   blue    green   yellow    red    white
```

How can I get these attributes? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your desired output? What columns would you like  the attributes contained in `foo` and `bar` to appear in? And supposing you were able to retrieve the attributes of `item` and `item2`, how should they be stored in these items' columns?

Comment: For attributes contained in `foo` and `bar`, the values could be repeated in its columns through the entire DataFrame. For `baz`, the values could be repeated through its entire level. Same for `item1` and `item2`. The columns could be generated with names `foo_bar1` or `item1_a`, for example - it's not a problem because I only have a few columns.

Comment: Thanks for following up @Vini. I believe you'll increase your chances of receiving an answer to your question if you include a visual example that is a *precise* representation of the desired output you described in your comment above. Reviewing these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) may be helpful.